# How to initialize a variable by instantiating a class and setting the class as its datatype?

Tags: java

In the main() method within the Main Class, create a variable called mathObject with the datatype set as MyMath.
   initialize the variable by instantiating the MyMath class

Comment: MyMath mathObject = new MyMath(); ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4xKihjI6HJ0

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of different ways to initialize a variable. Such as:

- Direct initialization (Main.java):

  ```
  public class Main {
      public static void main(String args[]){
          MyMath mathObject = new MyMath();
          System.out.println(mathObject.a);
      }
  }

  class MyMath {
      int a = 10;

      // constructors

      // getter & setter
  }
  ```
- With the object & target variable (Main.java):

  ```
  public class Main {
      public static void main(String args[]) {
          MyMath mathObject = new MyMath();
          mathObject.a = 10;
          System.out.println(mathObject.a);
      }
  }

  class MyMath {
      int a;

      // constructors

      // getter & setter
  }
  ```
- With the setter method (Main.java):

  ```
  public class Main {
      public static void main(String args[]){
          MyMath mathObject = new MyMath();
          mathObject.setA(10);
          System.out.println(mathObject.a);
      }
  }

  class MyMath {
      int a;

      // constructors

      // getter & setter
      public void setA(int a) {
          this.a = a;
      }
  }
  ```
- With the constructor (Main.java):

  ```
  public class Main {
      public static void main(String args[]){
          MyMath mathObject = new MyMath(10);
          System.out.println(mathObject.a);
      }
  }

  class MyMath {
      int a;

      // constructors
      public MyMath(int a) {
          this.a = a;
      }

      // getter & setter
  }
  ```